# Visual dynamic range question mod-closed - why?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, closed-questions

I just wished to bring up this question - I didn't write it, I didn't answer it, but I think it's a valid question - [How are colors outside the standard RGB color scheme perceived?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/56385/colors-outside-rgb).

If it was unanimously community-closed I would settle for it, but a mod-closure is a bit too much imho.

It received two answers and the accepted answer makes sense. I voted to re-open.

Comment: I agree and vote to re-open.

Comment: Sorry. If you just look at the question then there seems nothing biological about it. If you look at the answers then it seems fine. I did not see the answers. There were close to 100 items in the review queue and I therefore missed it. That is a separate issue but a serious one. Community moderation is not happening adequately. I don't wish to force moderate but other members should participate in the review process, actively.

Comment: @WYSIWYG - isn't that worth a meta post then?

Comment: Yes.. I have been thinking about it.